# Is It ok to invoke a method of a widget in test cases?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';

class QrCodeReader extends StatefulWidget {
  QrCodeReader(
      {required this.onSuccess,
      this.onFailure,
      this.allowDuplicates = false});

  final void Function(Barcode data) onSuccess;
  final void Function()? onFailure;
  final bool allowDuplicates;

  @override
  State<QrCodeReader> createState() => _QrCodeReaderState();
}

class _QrCodeReaderState extends State<QrCodeReader> {
  late MobileScannerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = widget.controller ?? MobileScannerController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.height,
      width: widget.width,
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Stack(children: [
        Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.camera_alt,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 50,
          ),
        ),
        MobileScanner(
            controller: _controller,
            allowDuplicates: widget.allowDuplicates,
            onDetect: (barcode, args) {
              if (barcode.rawValue == null) {
                widget.onFailure!();
              } else {
                widget.onSuccess(barcode);
              }
            }),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: BorderPainter(),
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I have to cover the onDetect function this is from the packages. I have found a way to call and cover the function in test cases

step 1 : Finding the widget MobileScanner using finder and save this in a variable

```
 final MobileScanner mobileScanner = tester.widget<MobileScanner>(find.byType(MobileScanner));
```

step 2 : Then I can access the methods of the widget like

```
 mobileScanner.onDetect(BarCode(value))
```

And we can  verify the needed . Thus we can invoke the function we can get the data that we pass here will enter into that specific blocs and also get the coverage for these lines Just want to make sure this approach is ok for the test cases ... you can contribute with your pros and cons for this method Pros and cons for the approach.

Is It ok To invoke a method of a widget in test cases